# calling to functions with polymorphic pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
class A{};
class AA:public A{};

struct X {
    void f(A *) {
        std::cout << "X::f(A*)\n";
    }
};

struct Y:public X {
    void f(A *) {
        std::cout << "Y::f(A*)\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Y *y = new Y();
    X *x = new Y();
    const X *cx = new Y();

    y->X::f(new AA);
    x->f(new AA);
}
```

Print:

> X::f(A*)
>
> X::f(A*)

I don't understand why `y->X::f(new AA)` and `x->f(new AA)` wont raise compilation error. I get that `X::f(A *)` is called in both of the cases. But what is the principle whereby the compiler chooses to use this method? Function overload with polymorphism? Any thumb rules?

Comment: Why would you expect an error actually? I don't get it.

Comment: In first case (**x->f(new AA)**) x is a pointer to base class X thats why _X::f(A*)_ is invoked. In second case (**y->X::f(new AA)**) you explicitly said that you are interested in method from base class by writing **X::**.

Comment: So many `new`... :-(

Comment: @AlexGoft, Your AA class inherits from A, that's why. There is let's say a hidden cast from derived class to the base class. You can try to look for topic like - _Automatic type conversion_.

Comment: In the future, you should reduce your example to a *minimal example* that still demonstrates the problem. In this case, that probably means getting rid of class `Y` altogether. The whole `X`/`Y` inheritance issue has nothing to do with your question, but the example made several of us think that calling `X::f` and `Y::f` was the focus of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question implies you expected the behavior you would have gotten if f had been declared virtual in X.  In some languages, that is the only possible behavior.  In C++ you have a choice.

As you declared f, it uses the compile time type so `x-f(new AA)` calls `X::f`  because `x` is an `X*`

If you had declared f virtual in X the `x-f(new AA)` would call `Y::f` because x points to a Y

For the other aspect of your question (why there is no error involved in calling X::f for a object of type Y), X is a base class of Y, so there should be a valid object of type X buried inside each object of type Y and that X object should be usable with any X method.

Until seeing above comments, I missed the third aspect of your question, that the compiler deduces the need for an implicit cast from `AA*` to `A*` when you pass an `AA*` to a method that needs an `A*` and `A` is a base class of `AA`.  That deduction is largely separate from the compile time or run time choice between X::f and Y::f

Answer (score 1):

The way your code currently is, if you do this:

```
y->X::f(new AA);
y->f(new AA);
x->f(new AA);
```

You'll get this:

```
X::f(A*)
Y::f(A*)
X::f(A*)
```

But, if you declare `X::f` as virtual, you'll instead get this:

```
X::f(A*)
Y::f(A*)
Y::f(A*)
```

Also, because `AA` is a child class of `A`, you can pass a pointer to `AA` where a pointer to `A` would be expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `x->f(new AA)` to call `Y::f()`, then you need to declare `X::f()` as `virtual.`

If `X::f()` is not declared as `virtual`, then (as `x` is a `X` pointer) `x->f(new AA)` calls `X::f()`.

See C++ standard section 10.3 "Virtual functions" (N3242):

> 1. Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented programming. A class that declares or
>      inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.
> 2. If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly
>      from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also `virtual` (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides `Base::vf`.